# gdb/lldb can't access memory address of jitted code

Tags: debugging, gdb, lldb, jit

I'm working on a JIT compiler and often need to debug the execution of jitted code in gdb/lldb. However, when trying to jump over a `call` during execution of jitted code using `nexti`, gdb errors with:

```
(gdb) nexti
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 0.
Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7fcc056
```

The same happens in lldb:

```
    frame #0: 0x00007ffff7fcc053
->  0x7ffff7fcc053: call   r11
    0x7ffff7fcc056: pop    r11
    0x7ffff7fcc058: pop    r10
    0x7ffff7fcc05a: pop    r9
(lldb) ni
warning: failed to set breakpoint site at 0x7ffff7fcc056 for breakpoint -2.1: error: 9 sending the breakpoint request
```

I get the same errors when trying to manually set a breakpoint at that address (e.g. `b *0x7ffff7fcc056`). I don't know if this has to do with the way we invoke the call (loading the address of the call symbol into a register and calling it this way), and gdb/lldb can't work out how to step over it. But that doesn't explain why setting the breakpoint to the address manually also doesn't work. Or is it because the code being executed is generated at runtime and only exists in memory and gdb/lldb attempt to match the address with the executable binary, where this address obviously doesn't exist?

I'm using the latest versions of gdb (9.2) and lldb (11). Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like both lldb & gdb are unable to switch the region you've written your JIT code into from "rx" to "rw" so that it can insert a trap.  You will probably get the same error if you tried `memory write` to that address.  We'd have to know more about the platform you are working on and how you handle the memory region into which you are inserting your JIT code to know why that's true.

Comment: Is that how gdb/lldb works? I didn't realise the code needs to be writeable. I thought executable is enough. You may have answer my question then. I am using [dynasm-rs](https://github.com/CensoredUsername/dynasm-rs) to generate the assembler code, which itself uses [memmap-rs](https://github.com/danburkert/memmap-rs) to allocate the memory. Before running the code it calls [make_exec](https://github.com/danburkert/memmap-rs/blob/master/src/unix.rs#L169), which marks the memory executable, but removes write permissions. So is gdb failing because the memory needs to be writeable as well?

Comment: lldb & gdb overwrite the instruction at which to set the breakpoint with a trap instruction.  That's how software breakpoints work.  However, the code doesn't have to be writable before the debugger gets to it.  After all, lldb can set breakpoints in "normal" code, and pretty much no systems map TEXT writable as that's a huge security hole.  Rather, lldb is able to switch the permissions to writeable and back.  If breakpoints are working on your system, then that is working for code loaded by the system & dynamic loader.  Looks like the way you are inserting your JIT code defeats that.

Comment: But I don't know enough about memmap-rs and/or make_exec to know how they manage to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! I think I understand a bit better what gdb does now and what the problem seems to be. Sadly, that doesn't get me much closer to a solution. Guess I'll have to keep poking around. I'll post and update once I know more.

Comment: Update: I have now found a workaround which allows me to set breakpoints in gdb again. Before executing the generated assembler I just manually mark its memory location as writeable using `libc::mprotect`. So the problem does, as you suggested, seem to be that gdb/lldb can't switch permissions themselves. Whether this is due to a bug or missing feature in the debuggers or due to the way dynasm/memmap allocate the compiled code I have not worked out yet.

Comment: Interesting.  I don't know what system you are working on, but for instance macOS won't execute code on a writeable page, so that's not a generally viable solution.  On those systems lldb and/or gdb have to be able to change permissions to writeable and back.  Again, given that you can set breakpoints in standard system library code which I'm pretty sure isn't mapped writeable, I'm pretty sure the debugger can change permissions on other regions, just not your JIT code.

Comment: Indeed. I am aware that this hack won't work on BSD and possibly some Linux distros. But it works on Debian and for now that was sufficient to debug the JIT code and find the issue I was stuck on. I'll probably have to come back to this in the future when we need to debug traces on other systems, but luckily that's not an immediate concern. I agree that it's weird that I can set breakpoints in other regions but not the one that contains my JIT code. I'm still curious as to why that is. If I ever find the reason I'll make sure to post it here.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll be interested to hear what it is.